# How to rebuild owl carousel inside bootstrap accordion?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, owl-carousel

I have a bootstrap accordion on my webpage, with 2 panels. One of which is open by default and other one is collapsed. Each of these panels have owl carousel in it. Owl carousel in first panel is working correctly, but when i open collapsed accordion panel then owl carousel in that panel is not properly shown.

Can anybody tell me how to reset/rebuild owl carousel in that collapsed accordion panel, when its opened.

Comment: You need to post your code or make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.collapsed').click(function() {
       $(this).next('.owl-carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
        $(this).next('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                }
            }
        });   
  });
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      responsive:{
          0:{
              items:1
          }
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
          <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
          <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Collapsible Group Item #3
      </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
          <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
          <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```